# SWT Disable shell fullscreen mode

Tags: java, windows, swt

Is there a way to disable fullscreen mode for shell in SWT?

```
new Shell(SWT.TOOL);
```

`SWT.TOOL` really hides a ful-screen button, but it also hide an icon of app. Also, you are still can double-click on the head of windows to fullscreen it or use fullscreen swipes in windows >=7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use these style bits:

```
final Shell shell = new Shell(display, SWT.CLOSE | SWT.TITLE | SWT.MIN);
```

**However**, you won't be able to resize the shell anymore by dragging the corners. If you add `SWT.RESIZE`, it will resize, but it will be maximizable again.